# 404 url not found when directory location moved (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this document root `/var/www/example` and then inside this directory I have a file `test.php`, and also my other project so the structure of the project looks like this

**/var/www/example**

```
├── .htaccess (Obs)
├── classes  
├── config
├── controllers
├── public
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── index.php 
│   ├── css
│   ├── index.php
│   └── js
├── test.php (Obs! not managed by .htaccess)
└── views
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^admin[/]?$ /example/admin/login [redirect]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ public/admin/index.php?page=$1&query=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ public/index.php?page=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

I recently moved the project from a MAMP server running on localhost to a domain-driven server. When I try my

> test.php

file  it works and `echo "It works"` as intendended but when I try running my site it doesn´t .

**error.log**

```
 [Mon Jul 29 18:02:52 2013] [error] [client 83.248.93.217] script '/var/www/example/index.php' not found or unable to stat
 [Mon Jul 29 18:02:52 2013] [error] [client 83.248.93.217] File does not exist:     /var/www/favicon.ico
 [Mon Jul 29 18:03:02 2013] [error] [client 83.248.93.217] File does not exist: /var/www/example/bordsoversikt
 [Mon Jul 29 18:03:02 2013] [error] [client 83.248.93.217] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

My controller maps some of the sites by names to corresponding files like so

**content of client_router** all calls goes through index.php as `htaccess` and then to the router...

```
public function initialize_routes() {
$this->routes = array(
    "bordsoversikt" => "page_table_overview",
    "bordsreservation" => "page_table_reservation",
    "reservationsprocess" => "script_reserve_form",
    "registrering" => "page_registration",
    "registreringsprocess" => "script_register_form",
    "lyckadregistrering" => "page_successfull_signup",
    "login" => "page_login",
    "logout" => "script_logout",
    "profil" => "page_home", 
    "klientlogin" => "script_login",
    "profil" => "page_profile",
    "sparaprofil" => "script_edit_profile_changes"
);
```

I assume there could be something wrong either with my htaccess file, why i posted the contents, or there could be something wrong with my `apache2.config` file. But Im quite new on configuring apache so I wont try to post parts of it, as I probably would post the uncritical parts. Can somebody please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please explain **what** fails! Check the apache `error.log` file!

Comment: allright, edited the question..

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess is used by apache?

Comment: @Marek No, im not? How do I know that?

Comment: Introduce an error into it and see if you get error 500 from apache

Comment: @Marek I don´t understand what you mean? How should I do that?

Comment: Put something invalid to .htaccess, random sequence of characters, whatever.

Comment: @Marek Tried it (wrote some gibberish in .htaccess), but nothing changed, still displays "not found" error and the error.log says the same thing as in the posted question... Does it mean that the htaccess does not get read?

Comment: Yes, it was not read. If AllowOverride is not set, apache does not even bother to read .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your htaccess file is readable by apache (e.g. on linux, `chmod 644 /var/www/example/.htaccess`)
2. Make sure your vhost or server config allows the override:

   ```
   AllowOverride FileInfo
   ```

   or better yet

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```
3. Something less likely, but look through your server/vhost config files for a command called [`AccessFilename`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename). This is usually **.htaccess** by default but if it's something different, then you need to either change it to **.htaccess** or rename your file to whatever the directive says it is.

Comment: Yes thank! This was the problem indeed. I needed to let my vhost AllowOverride All. But there where many vhost. If somebody has the same problem I suggest you find the one that relays to your site mine was for example in /var/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default